# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is pausing my Activity

Tags: android, mobile, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Targeting my App at SDK 23, I want to request permissions for location service,
inside my 'OnCreate' function i'm using this code:

```
    int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (hasPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("TEST", "GPS GRANTED");
    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                0);


    }
```

When my Activity creating itself, instead of asking for the permissions while showing the activity view on the screen, it suddenly pausing the activity, taking android to home screen and then showing the permission request dialog.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your activity will be called with `onPause()`, because the permission-request dialog is its own activity and it is taking over the foreground. As to why the home screen is appearing, that is rather strange.

Comment: indeed the issue was relate to the 'onPause()' method.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this code inside the onConnected() function.